# Many websites allow passwords equal to username or e-mail address. Is this not a security risk?

Tags: passwords, password-policy

I'm currently testing password policies on websites to get a feeling for what might be an acceptable policy/trade-off that provides good protection for our users without frustrating them.

I was surprised to find out that each and every website I tested allowed me to set a password that was equal to my username or e-mail address. If it couldn't be set to the username, it was only because it didn't meet the minimum length requirement. Equal to e-mail address worked every time. Even on sites that had rather strict policies otherwise.

Instinctively, I would think that this is no more secure than using a stupid password, such as "1234" or "password". I'm also pretty sure that [NIST SP 800-63B](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/SpecialPublications/NIST.SP.800-63b.pdf) advises against such context-specific passwords (i.e. containing application name, username or user e-mail address). Unfortunately, I cannot verify this claim, as the NIST publication seems to be currently unavailable due to the US government shutdown.

Am I wrong in thinking that such context-specific passwords should be treated in the same manner as "stupid" passwords? If yes, what am I not seeing?

ETA: I'm thinking technical reasons that might make one case not feasible for attackers. I understand there may be non-technical reasons for this, e.g. a product team wanting to allow users to copy & paste their e-mail addresses into both fields to quickly proceed and make a purchase.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. Are stupid passwords stupid? Yes. Is a website stupid for allowing this type of stupid password? No. Is it a security risk? Yes, but a risk to whom?

Comment: @schroeder I'm asking why, in many cases, one set of stupid passwords seems to be treated differently than another set. Perhaps there is a technical difference between the two cases that makes one case not feasible for attackers. I personally can't think of any such technical reason, which is why I'm asking. I will amend the question.

Comment: There is no reason except for the development and testing costs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct in that the NIST SP 800-63B does advise that verifiers check secrets "against a list that contains values known to be commonly-used, expected, or compromised:
....
Context-specific words, such as the name of the service, the username, and derivatives thereof."

From personal experience, I do remember interacting with services which have had this requirement: a Google search for a typical error message (["Passwords must not contain your username"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?rlz=1C5CHFA_enGB826GB826&ei=vddBXK_XOYevgwf62qjoDg&q=Passwords%20must%20not%20contain%20your%20username&oq=Passwords%20must%20not%20contain%20your%20username&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i22i30.12272.15868..15960...1.0..0.235.5564.0j35j1......0....1..gws-wiz.....6..0i71j35i39j0i67j0i131j0j0i131i67j0i20i263j0i13i30.DMQGPTwpqUA)) does show that services out there are following NIST advice.

On the topic of implementing NIST, it also recommends against "repetitive or sequential characters (e.g. ‘aaaaaa’, ‘1234abcd’)". I don't see this implemented as often as other secret verification.

tl;dr: You're not wrong about the NIST specification.